# Android toolbar designing

Tags: java, android, toolbar

So as far as I know there are two ways which I can design `toolbar`.
I can just go `<TextView>` and write whatever I want to have in the toolbar and maybe go `<Button>` as well just below `<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>`. But the standard way which is suggested by Google and many other people seems to be by using `<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>` which allows you to inflate toolbar when you code your activity.
So I have a few questions about this

1. What is the difference of the two methods? i.e is there any advantage of using one over another except the fact that I have to copy and paste for every activity when I just add `<TextView>`, etc..
2. I just can't seem to be able to find a way to get rid of the title of the activity being set to the title of the toolbar when I use `<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>`. I know where to change the text but how do I remove it completely?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. What is the difference of the two methods? i.e is there any advantage of using one over another except the fact that I have to
>      copy and paste for every activity when I just add , etc..

If you use Toolbar you can use the menu, home back button like features which you can't easily setup with a TextView or Button.

> 2. I just can't seem to be able to find a way to get rid of the title of the activity being set to the title of the toolbar when I use
>      . I know where to change
>      the text but how do I remove it completely?

To remove title either use

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

or

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);
```

Comment: You can also do it by changing the theme of particular `activity` or base theme to remove title or toolbar implementing `Theme.NoTitleBar`, but then it will become a `fullscreen activity`

Comment: so is there no way I can design toolbar in the layout xml file? so say I want to center a text and put an icon on the left side, would that be also done in the activity code?

Comment: in xml add the imageview and textview in toolbar then align as you wish... to set the title dynamically get the textview instance in toolbar then setText

Comment: yea well that's kinda the problem I have right now because when I add TextView or ImageView, it will go under my toolbar not on toolbar.

Comment: I'm thinking it has to be set somewhere between the `<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>` brackets but I can't create TextView in there